# What does \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit} mean?

Tags: biblatex, citing, conditionals

Pardon the newbie question.  I see this in the first part of a `\DeclareCiteCommand` and I'm not sure what it means.  Google has not returned any joy.

Here's an example

```
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
    \ifciteseen
    {....
```

Many thanks again for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to do something in particular? The command says "set the boolean `cbx@loccit` to false globally".  But I don't think that such an answer is likely to be very helpful to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\cite` macro globally sets the boolean switch `loccit` to false. (`cbx@` is biblatex's internal prefix for citation macros.) The `loccit` switch is used by some of the `verbose` bibliography/citation styles. See section 4.6.2 of the biblatex documentation for a description of `\ifloccit` (and the similar `\ifopcit`).